# How do I change a MySQL table to UTF-8?

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, utf-8

I know there are many settings for a language for a table and a database.

I already created the database.  I believe when I created it, it was default/LATIN.  I want to change everything-I mean...**both the table and the database, to UTF-8**.

How can I do that? thanks.

Answer (score 60):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is complete. From my understanding, this will attempt to convert all the columns to the given character set, but may or may not change the table default. It also doesn't address the database default. I'll post my approach as a separate answer

Comment: Just to clarify, this command does change the table default but does not affect the database default.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [Using alter command to change character set](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0080__Table/Usingaltercommandtochangecharacgterset.htm).

Another useful link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-table.html

The general form is

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [[DEFAULT] COLLATE collation_name]
```

and for a specific column in a table

```
ALTER TABLE column COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

---

- [MySQL’s character sets and collations demystified](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysqls-character-sets-and-collations-demystified)
- [MySQL Forums :: Change Collation](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,59697,72634#msg-72634)

Comment: Developer-Sid 's answer, plus this answer, form a complete answer

Answer (score 4):

aioobe's answer tells how to change the character set of a database, table or column. You should keep in mind that

- setting the character set for a table just specifies the default character set for new columns in that table. It doesn't change the character set for preexisting columns; you have to do those columns individually, OR if you want to change every single string-type column in the table to the same character set there's a command you can use to do that: "alter table ... convert to character set" ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html )
- if you already have data that is stored mis-encoded in a column, then using "alter table ... modify" to change the column will not quite solve the problem. For example, if you're been storing UTF-8 data in a Latin1 column and you change the character set directly from Latin1 to UTF-8, it'll still be mis-encoded afterwards. This can be worked around by converting from Latin-1 to UTF-8 via binary.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "via binary"?

Comment: it means converting to something like BLOB first then converting to UTF-8 (or whatever) because changing to binary doesn't do any kind of conversion

Comment: After I converted my database through binary now in phpmyadmin all "client name" fields show as "[blob 11b]" instead of the client name. Even for those records that are plain ascii. Now what?

Answer (score 2):

1) Database default character set and collation:

```
SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
```

Altered via: `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

2) Table default character set and collation:

```
SELECT T.table_name, CCSA.character_set_name 
FROM information_schema.TABLES T, information_schema.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY CCSA 
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation AND T.table_schema = "YOUR_DB";`
```

Altered via: `ALTER TABLE [table_name] CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`

3) Column character set and collation:

```
SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.CHARACTER_SET_NAME, c.COLLATION_NAME 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.table_schema = "YOUR_DB";`
```

Altered via: `ALTER TABLE [table_name] CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`

The third one requires that you disable foreign key checks for the data conversion. So putting this all together:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE migrate_charset_to_utf8()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE curr_table VARCHAR(64);

    DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT T.table_name
      FROM information_schema.TABLES T
      WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND
        T.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DB';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN table_cursor;

    table_loop: LOOP
      FETCH table_cursor INTO curr_table;
      IF done THEN
        LEAVE table_loop;
      END IF;

      # Convert table data(columns) charset
      SET @sql_str1 = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", curr_table, " CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
      PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_str1;
      EXECUTE stmt1;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

      # Set table's default charset e.g for new columns added
      SET @sql_str2 = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", curr_table, " CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
      PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql_str2;
      EXECUTE stmt2;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

    END LOOP table_loop;

    CLOSE table_cursor;
  END//

DELIMITER ;


SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
CALL migrate_charset_to_utf8();
SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

EDIT: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8) instead

Answer (score -2):

Add to your my.cnf this:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
default-collation=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And restart mysqld deamon.

**ADDED:**

```
ALTER DATABASE your_base_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and my.cnf

```
SET collation_connection     = utf8_unicode_ci;
SET character_set_results    = utf8;
SET character_set_connection = utf8;
SET character_set_client     = utf8;
```

Comment: This **won't** change character set of the existing databases or tables

Comment: Yes, but it's at least he solved the character problem at all. Change db/table chars he could simply with phpMyAdmin...

Comment: provided he has php/httpd/phpMyAdmin installed.

Comment: Nope none of that stuff. I just have a basic database and tables.  What do I type? It should be pretty simple, right?

Comment: @Alexander I just gave one of the solutions, you are not... Maybe it's not the best one, but still one of the answers :)

Comment: @mosg, I'm not giving an answer, because aioobe has already written it faster than me :)