# FONT not displaying certain characters

Tags: php, mysql, html, font-face

I am using a custom font on the [website](http://auto-sal.es) i'm developing and some basic characters are not being displayed. What seems to be the problem?

Also i am fetching the content from MYSQL.

[image: font characters]

Is the font bad?

```
@font-face {font-family: Cabin_Regular; src: url('fonts/Cabin_Regular.ttf');}
@font-face {font-family: Lobster; src: url('fonts/Lobster.ttf');}
body, select, input, textarea {font-family: 'Cabin_Regular';color:white;font-size: 16px;text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em black;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-family: 'Lobster'; margin-bottom: 0;padding-bottom: 0;margin-top: 0; padding-top: 0;}
```

Comment: If the glyphs don't exist in the font itself (you can check on your local computer), you're going to have to either replace the symbols with a CSS font, or use standard characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the encoding in your MySQL database. 
If it's not UTF-8 you're going to have issues

if it isn't UTF-8 use the following after you've connected to the database  and are about to execute a Query

> ```
> mysql_set_charset('utf8',$database_Connection);
> ```

Also make sure you have the charset defined in the `<head>` of your html document

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
> ```

...
I actually ran into this problem myself once when using a client's database which was set to Latin1. A real pain to figure out the first time.

Comment: In my headers i got utf, and when i populated the database i didnt specify a charset, i went an exported a found out the default is `) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;` what can i do? how do i change it

Comment: use the mysql_set_charset('utf8',$Your_database_Connection); function just before you run your queries.
That'll change the charset to UTF-8 while the query is being run.

Comment: Thanks, i changed it in the database and all the tables are set to utf-8 `ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;`

Comment: I don't think you can change the default charset in your database after it's been set. You'll have to export all your data, and repopulate a newly created Database.

Comment: oh ok, I was wrong then. That's good to know. Is it working now?

Comment: no lol, seems theres a problem with the characters like david said

Comment: do the characters display normally if you use a basic sans-serif font?

Comment: Nope, here check [link](http://auto-sal.es/contactus.php) I tried sans family but didnt work, for instance, the £ pound symbol isn't showing with neither font

Comment: ok in that case definitely try using the `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$database_Connection);` before you execute your query in the php (I assume its PHP?).

Comment: Lol that worked, but why, the tables and the database and the pages were already set to utf8, im i missing something

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9661/discussion-between-jose-david-garcia-llanos-and-digitalbiscuits)

Comment: Sorry man, I gotta go to bed now. 
...I'll leave you with this though. The comment here will explain why the Charset in your table didn't change

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6116205/1097858

Answer (score 3):

First check if the characters are encoded for example the copyright symbol should be `&copy;` in the database.

Second check if the font even supports the character some fonts don't have all of the glyphs you want. What are the characters suppose to be?

Comment: Yeah seems &copy; works for copyright i was using the copyright symbol directly

Comment: Thanks i didnt know the characters in the database had to be encoded, &pound; is for £

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly an encoding issue. See http://ask.metafilter.com/mefi/28045 for some solutions.

To clarify, everything (PHP, MySQL, and even their conneciton to eachother) needs to be communicating in the same encoding or the same entities will be rendered differently. The standard is utf-8, but the important issue isn't really which is used but that it is used uniformly. There are good suggestions on how to get everything on the same page in the above link.

Comment: I didnt specify a charset when populating the db, however it seems that it is set to `ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`