# convert utf8 characters using PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pdo, character-encoding

I'm not sure if someone has asked this question before or not but I didn't find any. While I hadn't set connection charset in PDO and table collation was `utf8_percian_ci`, so all data has been stored in unreadable characters like `Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…` that is `سلام` in Persian.

Before setting charset by adding `mysql:charset=utf8mb4;` to PDO DNS I was able to retrieve all data correctly but now I see `Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…` instead of `سلام` in browser.

My website is a blog and now it seems I have to reenter all the texts and posts and then restore them to be saved correctly. That's a disaster!

I used `mb_detect_encoding()` for both `Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…` & `سلام` and found out that both of them are UTF-8. This is so funny to search "How to convert utf8 to utf8 ?" and absolutely I get no expected result.

Is there anyway to convert `Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…` to `سلام` using MySQL ? If not, I thought another way could be using PHP to read old data then convert and insert into database again.

What should I do ?

Comment: have you tried with utf8_general_ci ?

Comment: I have tried that. The problem is not just about output encoding

Comment: @HarshalMahajan No, but I know just changing the collation won't make any change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert wrongly encoded data to UTF-8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151835/how-to-convert-wrongly-encoded-data-to-utf-8)

Comment: @deceze Exactly works ! You're the man of unicode ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```sql
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = BINARY CONVERT(my_column USING latin1)
```

(where `latin1` is the character set in which your connection was set at the time of insertion).

Comment: Nice Answer , Thank you