# Liquibase: How to set Charset UTF-8 on MySQL database tables?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, utf-8, liquibase

My `Liquibase` changeset looks like

```
<changeSet id="05192014.1525" author="h2">
        <createTable tableName="network">
            <column name="network_id" type="BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(300)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="active" type="TINYINT(1)" defaultValue="1">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="created_at" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultValueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="created_by" type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
            <column name="updated_at" type="TIMESTAMP"/>
            <column name="updated_by" type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

- I have integrated liquibase with `Maven` using plugin
- When I run `mvn clean install`, it creates `MySQL` table like

> CREATE TABLE `network` (   `network_id` bigint(19) unsigned NOT NULL, 
>   `name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,   `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT
>   '1',   `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   `created_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,   `updated_at` timestamp NULL
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `updated_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY
>   (`network_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Everything looks good except `CHARSET=latin1`

**Question**

How can I make `CHARSET=UTF-8`?

Comment: Have you tried to [force-replace](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html) it to the required value?

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [modifySql element](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html) after your create table definition:

```
</createTable>
<modifySql dbms="mysql">
    <append value="ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=UTF8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci"/>
</modifySql>
```

Comment: Is it possible to write inside a separate as on starting the db migration process, it will fire an error if the database is already deployed elsewhere.?

Comment: or this

       `</createTable>
     <modifySql>
       <append value=" ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"/>
     </modifySql>
    </changeSet`

Comment: Am I right that these changes will need to be added manually? I'm hoping liquibase would detect this as part of `liquibase:diff`

Answer (score 10):

If needing per-column specification of charset/collate (as you may want different charsets for your columns), the following has worked for me (just appending CHARACTER SET and COLLATE clauses to the `type` attr value of `column`):

```
    <createTable tableName="my_table">
        <column name="some_column" type="VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci" >
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
    <createTable tableName="my_table">
        <column name="some_column" type="VARCHAR(20)" >
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <modifySql dbms="mysql">
        <replace replace="VARCHAR(20)" with="VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci" />
    </modifySql>
```

You can omit `CHARACTER SET` but not `COLLATE`.

Comment: Which Liquibase version did you tested this with? Does not seem to work in 3.4.1

Comment: @jso It was tested with version 3.5.3.

Comment: The second worked for me. The modifySql must come after all the createTable elements, and you may need to move other elements into another changeSet.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the documenation, Charset is database dependent, and if that is the case, judging from the documentation you can use

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html

Looking at the MySql documentation you could probably just plug this line in:

```
<sql>ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;</sql>
```

Comment: does not work when you have foreign key(s) in the table

Answer (score 1):

Usually the configuration of the charset is done on  database creation time, and you should configure it on your liquibase config file like this:

```
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabasename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

for more info see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html

or if you already have a database created with a different charset you could try to convert it see:

[How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)