# Encoding issue with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, character-encoding

I have a MySQL table which I set to use the encoding `utf8_swedish_ci`. Two example values are `2 Kung` and `1 Krön` - note the swedish character. I need to search on these internationalized strings from within a PHP script. My PHP file is encoded in `UTF-8`. My code, with error handling stripped for clarity, looks like this:

```
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $user);
$db->set_charset('UTF-8');
$stm = $db->prepare('SELECT `id` FROM `myTable` WHERE `bok` LIKE ?');
echo "Searching on $value'...";
$stm->bind_param('s', $value);
$stm->execute();
$stm->bind_result($result);
$stm->close();
echo "Fetched '$result'.";
```

Now if I set $value to the first example value, I get the single matching row. With the other example value I get no rows. I have tested the queries to work in PHPMyAdmin. I figure the error lies with the international character and therefore that I messed up the encodings somewhere. So what did I do wrong and how do I fix this?

**Edit**: the line `$db->set_charset('UTF-8');` fails because I used an incorrect charset. It should be `utf8`. Turns out I had too little error handling, I should've checked `$db->error` after `set_charset`.

Comment: Where you went wrong: You didn't specify an encoding when you created the table, so it used the default. How to fix it: [Change the encodings to be consistent.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)

Comment: @Sammitch why do you think he didn't specify encoding? @David try set names and use backticks in column and table names because if you don't in some cases it can cause problem. Also did you check if the `$value` is correct?

Comment: @Sammitch I did specify the encoding of the table.
@LaciK I actually use backticks everywhere, removed them when I pulled together the example. I used `echo $value` so I'm confident it has the right value.

Comment: Also note, this is `utf8` and not `UTF-8` for MySQL (`Unknown character set: 'UTF-8'`)

Comment: @julp That's it! I used the wrong name for the character encoding. Please add this as an answer so I can give you credit for solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $db->set_charset('UTF-8');
> ```

Note that MySQL is particular, the name it uses internally for the UTF-8 character set is `utf8` (without dash), not the regular `UTF-8`.

In case of doubt, refer to `SHOW CHARACTER SET;` ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it might help.

```
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $user);
$db->set_charset('UTF-8');
$stm = $db->prepare('SELECT `id` FROM `myTable` WHERE `bok` LIKE ?');
$value = '%'.$value.'%'; //added this line
$stm->bind_param('s', $value);
$stm->execute();
$stm->bind_result($result);
$stm->close();
echo "Fetched '$result'.";
```

I tried LIKE '' with UTF-8 chars on a char(180) column with utf8_general_ci encoding and it returned 0 rows so I tried it with LIKE %''% and that worked

Comment: But I'm not using utf8_general_ci, I'm using utf8_swedish_ci. I tried your suggestion and it didn't make any difference.