# to change language of database content in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with chinese website which is built in wordpress. And database is also in chinese language. So i want to change the language of database content. I had tried many plugins and some changes in wp-config file but i did not solve my issue.So what is the solution? please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "change language"? Are you thinking about *translating* it?

Comment: yes i want to translate chinese content of database to english.

Answer (score 1):

Well, translating the content of a website from one language to another is not trivial, or something that a plugin can just do.

You may be able to use some translation service but you would most likely end up with rather poor results. Try it, translate some Chinese text to English. It tends to be quite comical.

The only way of translating a website is to do it manually. It will be tedious, and take up quite a bit of your time, but there is no (to my knowledge) automated way of doing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right , what you are looking for is to change the char set of your database .

For example , if you run this query :

```
show variables like "character_set_database";
```

or :

```
show variables like "collation_database";
```

And also :

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE `db_name` (this is more to export your database)
```

You should get an output with the characters set for this specific database that you have. Let's say this for example :

```
character_set_database  latin1
```

Now , after the theory . I believe that what you need to run is this query :

```
ALTER DATABASE DB_name CHARACTER SET big5 COLLATE big5_bin;
```

One useful reference: [How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen can you explain why it is incorrect? How do we actually change the char set of a database if not that way?

Comment: Read the comments to the original question. The question is about translating content from one language to another, not about character sets.