# UTF-8 with php pdo and mysql - ctype php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, encoding, utf-8

How to use ctype_alpha with UTF-8

I have this code:

```
 if(empty($_POST) === false) {      

                if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && !empty ($_POST['first_name'])){
                    if (ctype_alpha($_POST['first_name']) === false) {
                    $errors[] = 'Please enter your First Name with only letters!';
                    }   
                }
```

so here I chech is everzthing fine if not I got error...

But If I use letters like ščćž - UTF-8 then I also get errors, so how I can sovle this problem becouse I need for first name to have onlz letters but I need to allow UTF-8 characters like ščćž

Please help!

Comment: Can you show us your database connection please?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FBFPT.png

Comment: your dsn should be like `mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdb;charset=utf8`

Comment: I put that  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname'], $config['username'], $config['password'],array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")); $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: probbalz problem is ctype_alpha

Comment: Btw, `$_POST` and `$_GET` always returns string or int, sometimes array, so if you want to use ctype, you should first convert them. Btw2 you do not really need to do security on inputs if you use PDO prepare queries

Comment: btw (again) you should read this ^^ http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Your problem is that you get your own error "Please use only alfabetic characters"?! That would pretty obviously be because `ctype_alpha` only matches very few alphanumeric characters, as it's supposed to. What are you using it for?!

Comment: message must be: Please enter your First Name with only letters! but if letters is ććšž. then also must accept that

Comment: From the doc : ctype is kind of regex like `[A-Za-z]` so this is just not the good function for that man ...

Comment: mu first name must be onlz letters , also last name

Comment: so if I remove that doeas I get securitz problem ... I update this with PDO prepare ...

Comment: @milemilicmile i think i have a solution for you :)

Comment: @milemilicmile just added answer, it was too long for a comment ^^

Comment: I update mz question

Comment: Instead of `if (x === false)` try `if (!x)`, it's much more concise.

Comment: @tadman read doc about `===` and `==` the `!` operator does not make it strict, the `===` does ;)

Comment: @Bob0t Are you expecting the function to return something totally insane? It's going to return a boolean. It's not necessary to strictly compare unless you need to differentiate between literal `false` and other logically false values. The description is "Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE." not "Returns FALSE sometimes, MAYBE on random occasions and LOL when feeling smarmy."

Comment: he talks a lot about security, just give him what he wants, a buffer overflow can make this returning some funny results :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make sure that EVERYTHING is in UTF8 NOBOM format. ALL php files must be saved in UTF8 NOBOM format. Adding just "charset=UTF-8" to html tag is not enough.

Also you have to set UTF8 for database connection:

mysql_query ('SET NAMES utf8');

Comment: for database I have: $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname'], $config['username'], $config['password'],array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: also make sure to convert the DB to UTF. Check [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)

Comment: also I have html text like:       <h3>Podešavanja.</h3> <p><b>Ovde možete izmeniti bitne informacije o vašoj firmi.</b></p>
 and everythong is fine, so everything is showed well

Comment: ctype_alpha for utf-8 . HOW?

Answer (score -2):

```
Please look at the below line

 if (ctype_alpha($_POST['last_name']) === false) {
                    $errors[] = 'Please use only alfabetic charecters';
                    } 



if you see condition of the ctype_alpha it is telling that if it is not contain an alphabet then throw an error, you need to remove that condition.


I hope this helps you.
```

Comment: but I need this code as security from attacks, from adding script at my base... I add this setLocale(LC_CTYPE, 'SR_sr.UTF-8'); to page

Comment: Not sure that for database you have serbian collation. Last time I checked it didn't exist so I used slovenian, the most similar one...

Comment: @milemilicmile, for preventing security attack you have other methods better than this one, like using prepared queries, using mysql_real_escape_string() function.

Comment: @milemilicmile,  in the condition of ctype_alpha make it equal to true instead of false, because at present the condition means that if it is not a normal character then it will throw the error

Comment: @milemilicmile, you updated the question but did not listen to my suggestion to turn the false to true in the above code if condition.