# How to convert non-readable utf8 chars in MySQL to readable

Tags: php, mysql

I have Arabic text stored in mysql like this format

```
Ø´Ù‚Ù‚ Ø¬Ø¯ÙŠØ¯Ù‡ ØºØ¨Ø± Ù…Ø³ÙƒÙˆÙ†Ù‡ 220 Ù…ØªØ±..
.150Ù…ØªØ±..Ø·Ø¨Ø±Ø¨ÙˆØ± ..Ø§Ø§Ø³ÙƒØ§Ù†Ø§Øª Ù‚Ù…ÙˆÙ… 
ÙˆØ§Ù„Ù†Ø¬Ø§Ø± Ù„Ù„Ø§Ø³ØªÙØ³Ø§Ø±
```

it is in this format because I didn't use the below before inserting data into database from HTML textboxes:

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

My question now, how to convert the text into MySQL columns to readable text like this:

```
شقق جديده غبر مسكونه 220 متر ..150متر..طبربور ..ااسكانات قموم والنجار للاستفسار
```

I tried the below for one column cell to check,  but it didn't work:

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

$sql  = 'SELECT content FROM messages WHERE id=500';
$qry = mysql_query($sql);
$result =mysql_fetch_object($qry);

$text= $result->content;

mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

$sql  ='UPDATE messages SET content= "'.$text.'" where id=500';
mysql_query($sql);
```

**Note:** if I use the below

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

before I insert data into database from HTML textarea, then it works fine for store and read, but I need to convert the already entered data into tables.

Thanks.

**The solution in brief can be done in 3 simple steps:**

A. Change the Database collation to utf8 via the command below:

```
ALTER DATABASE <db_name> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

already the table cells I want to change have collation of utf8_general_ci

B. Implement this query to change the content:

```
update messages set content=CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(content USING latin1) USING utf8);
```

C. add the below before you connect to the DB:

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

And you are done!!! Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ALTER DATABASE` and `ALTER TABLE` commands.

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8).

Comment: How it did not work? What did you run, how did it fail, what was the error message

Comment: That's not enough. You didn't provide any change of content in table cells, you should implement this query:

update messages set content=CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(content USING latin1) USING utf8);