# Converting your MySQL database to UTF8

Tags: mysql, database, moodle

I had to rebuild a moodle system from scratch having already the database from a previus version, i went to the repository and download the exact version of the moodle in this case was 1.9, installed it using the previus database installed.
The moodle ask me to change the charset so..
If you have phpmyadmin go to operations (French wrench icon) and go to charset, change to utf8_general_ci.

Comment: see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line script in Moodle 2+ which can do this for you.

Make sure your database is backed up, then type

```
php admin/cli/mysql_collation.php --collation=utf8_general_ci
```