# get Malformed JSON: Unexpected '?' in mysqli_fetch_row result

Tags: php, mysql, json, malformed

I execute this select statement on my table

```
$get_ads_by_category_query = "select name from sorvy_djcf_items where cat_id='38'";

if(mysqli_select_db($conn,'joyshopp_adds')){

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $get_ads_by_category_query);

    if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
       $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result;
       echo $row[0];
    }
```

When I execute this query return Malformed JSON: Unexpected '?' in browser do you know why this happen???

Do you have a solution?

I also saw this [How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8) and tried to change the database collation to utf8 but it did not worked...

Comment: You're not echoing JSON, you're just echoing the name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode` to return a JSON response.

```
echo json_encode($row[0]);
```

Comment: That sounds like it may be a collation issue, I'm not sure. But you're not getting the "Malformed JSON" error any more, are you?

Comment: i know it may be a collation issue but i changed database collation to utf8_general_ci but not worked,i also get "Malformed JSON:N"