# PHP Website Encoding issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, notepad++

I received a website , first of all i will provide some explanation:
Website PHP 5.3
Mysql Database and table charset LATIN1
Meta Tags used in files are windows 12...

Now first issue is that when i see index.php file in my PC Notepad++ it shows me Arabic there but when i see the same file in my windows server notepad++ it shows different encoding.

Second i have this website which is not showing data in Arabic in browser and all the data in database is in different format/garbage characters.

Any help

Comment: Your table has the charset **LATIN1**, you need to change the charset to **UTF-8**!

Comment: If i changed the charset of Database + Table +  Column so the data will not be distrub ?? @Charlotte Dunios

Comment: It will, because the data is in latin1. You should've set the charset of the database and whole table to UTF-8 before inserting any data.

Comment: Brother i have this website and i need to host it . The client said me to do this i can not insert data again.

Comment: This question is unclear, since it does not state what actually is desired.

Comment: @Arkascha-- There are 2 issues i am facing
The main issue is that i need to host this website properly working means showing arabic.

Comment: @GIJoes Have you tried the answer bellow?

Comment: Yes nothing happen..

Comment: How did you try, please comment on the answer how and show what you did so we can look at what to try

Comment: ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; i tried these lines in mysql and then checked the encoding it is utf8

Comment: What is the name of the database you are using and the name of the table in the database?

Comment: database name sdlc_demo and table admin

Comment: i have edited my answer bellow, can you try running these commands?

Comment: @GIJoes did my edited answer work?

Comment: Dear bro.. I am a programmer also i know in your previous answer that name of the database and table should be changed according to my database name...

Comment: Ok, well the bellow answer will work.  How are you running the sql?

Comment: Need some more info to help you...   Are you seeing Mojibake?  Or question marks?  `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` to see what is stored in table.  For example, Arabic letter `hah` will be hex `D8AD`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using these commands;

```
ALTER DATABASE sdlc_demo CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE admin CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

[How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)

Comment: **Caution:** `CONVERT TO` should be used _only_ in the case where "A table is declared to be latin1 and correctly contains latin1 bytes, but you would like to change it to utf8."