# Can I convert MySQL database character set from latin1 to utf8 without losing data?

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I want to convert my database to store unicode symbols.

Currently the tables have:

**`latin_swedish_ci`** collation and **`latin1`** character set

OR

**`utf8_general_ci`** collation and **`utf8`** character set

I am not sure how the existing data is encoded, but I suppose it is **`utf-8`** encoded, as I am using Django which I think encodes the data in **`utf-8`** before sending to the database.

My question is:
Can I convert the tables to **`utf8_unicode_ci`** collation and **`utf-8`** character set using the following queries without messing up the existing data? (as sugested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8?lq=1) post)

`ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

`ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

*Considering latin1 is subset of utf-8, I think it sould work. What do you guys think?*

Thank you in advance.

P.S: The version of MySQL is: 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latin1 is not a subset of UTF-8 - ASCII is. Latin1, however, is represented in Unicode.

`CONVERT TO` should work, as long as the data was stored in the correct encoding in the first place. Django may have used UTF-8 on the database connection, but the database should have re-encoded on the fly.

To check the actual encoding used - Use the `mysql` command-line tool to execute an SQL query that selects a row that you know contains non-ASCII characters. Then use the mysql `HEX()` function to check the bytes used. If you see bytes greater than > `0x7f`, check that they don't correspond to valid characters in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout

Comment: last_name='RÖNSCH'
HEX(substring(last_name,2,1)) returns 'c396'

What does this mean?

Comment: `select hex(last_name) from ...`

Comment: Although from Django documentation:


"All of Django’s database backends automatically convert Unicode strings into the appropriate encoding for talking to the database. They also automatically convert strings retrieved from the database into Python Unicode strings. You don’t even need to tell Django what encoding your database uses: that is handled transparently. "

Comment: `select hex(last_name) from...` returns '52C3964E534348' where Ö is c396

Comment: So it is safe to use `CONVERT TO`? @Alastair

Comment: No! It may double encode. Backup your database, then just do `ALTER`

Comment: Is it possible there is **latin1** encoded data also? As currently that is database's character set is latin1?

Comment: Has anyone run into this issue when converting from latin1 to utf8mb4? "Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes". Is there a way to shorten all of my constraint names without reducing the length of my VARCHAR fields?

Comment: @mihow it's probably best that you ask a new question. Be sure to include all the information including steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `c396` sitting in a `latin1` column, and you want it to mean `Ö`, then you are half way to "double encoding".  Do *not* use `CONVERT TO`; that will really get you into "double encoding".

Instead, you need the [2-step ALTER](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#2_step_alter).

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

If you have already messed it up further, and now the `Ö` is hex `C383E28093`, then you need to [fix double encoding](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixing_double_encoding_).

This gets you the latin1 byte in 2 steps:

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('C383E28093') USING utf8) USING latin1) --> 'Ã–' (C396)
HEX(CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('C396') USING utf8) USING latin1)) --> 'Ö' in latin1 (D6)
```

This gets you the 2-byte utf8 encoding:

```
CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('C383E28093') USING utf8) USING latin1)) USING utf8)
```

Do you want the column to be latin1?  Or utf8?

Comment: I want all tables to be utf-8 encoded. I had `c396` sitting in `latin1` column which meant `Ö`. Then I used 

`ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

 (no errors or warnings displayed by `MySQL`). 

Now when I use HEX() on the row with value `Ö` it returns `c396` again.

Comment: This means I didn't do "double encoding", although I had run `CONVERT TO` . Also I can store unicode symbols in this table now. It seems I did the right thing. Or no?

Comment: I don't know what you did exactly, but I tried it and got hex `C383E28093` -- double-encoding.  Please show me `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.