# special charactors not importing into mysql database

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8

I'm importing a csv saved as utf8 in linux, which looks fine. The tables in the mysql db are set for utf8 and so is the connection collation. I'm importing using "CSV using LOAD DATA" with the character set as UTF8. Yet the characters are being changed. eg ∙ becomes âˆ™ . What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is that your MySQL database uses the `utf8` encoding. This is because `utf8` in MySQL is not equivalent to the general UTF-8 encoding, but supports only a subset of the UNICODE characters. For instance, you cannot encode mathematical characters like `∙`, the Bullet Operator.

If you want a full support for all the UNICODE characters, you should try to use the `utf8mb4` encoding instead, as it is shown in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html):

> `utf8`, a UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to three bytes per character.
>
> `utf8mb4`, a UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to four bytes per character.

You can see also the full discussion about UNICODE support in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode.html).

Comment: You should change the setting inside the database itself, changing the encoding of the tables, not the import settings of the command.

Comment: See for instance [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38284057/2382734) or similar posts about changing MySQL encoding.

Comment: if I change the settings in the columns effected and upload using that setting it doesnt make any difference. I dont see a way to change the whole db, maybe that needs to be done. I have uploaded to this db before without problems using utf8, altho the csv would have been made on windows.

Comment: I found a work around, but due to the question being downvoted so much I will be posting it elsewhere, although I thank Renzo for his input

Comment: The "bullet operator", hex `E28899` is available in MySQL's utf8; utf8mb4 in not requires.