# Issue Storing Arabic Chars in Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to make a registration form where people will take the link and enter their information, which then gets stored in the database. Unfortunately, when I try to enter information in Arabic using the form ,it gets stored in database as an unknown chars.

I have tried the following without success.

- Set the default charset in the index as follows:

  ```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  ```
- Set the default charset in the database handler page:

  ```
  $cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf_8';
  $cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
  ```
- Changed the database Collation to `utf8_general_ci`
- Changed the table Collation to `utf8_general_ci`
- Exported as sql and edit the charset but I found it UTF-8 already.
- Made sure that my browser unicode is set to UTF-8.

And that's an example on how it works:

```
<form action="signup.php" method="POST" class="form">
<input type="text" name="first"><br />
<input type="text" name="uid"><br />
<input type="date" name="dob"><br />
```

-

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO students (first, uid, dob)
 VALUES ('$first','$uid', '$dob')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

And they're connected through a required file to connect to the db.

```
$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf_8';
$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test2");

if (!$conn ) {
    die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());

}
```

No idea what's causing this and I need a fast fix.

That's how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiQwJ.png

Comment: what is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE students`?

Comment: students
CREATE TABLE `students` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL ...

Comment: Search for (mysql and arabic) or (mysql and mojibake).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two possible suggestions:

Set your mysqli connection to utf-8 via [set_charset()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) or if that fails you can use [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

So for example,

```
if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($conn));
}
```

and if that fails or if you wish to use both in conjunction you could just do something like so as well:

```
$first = mb_convert_encoding($first, "UTF-8");
// and so forth
```

Comment: The first code worked perfectly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue you are having relates to character sets but on a per-column basis.  If you created the tables and databases **before** changing the character sets then it's possible not all character sets were changed.

Verify my suspicions by reviewing the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` similar to below:

```
mysql> show create table arabic;
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table                                                  |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| arabic | CREATE TABLE `arabic` (
  `words` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Notice the column `words` still has the charset `latin1`. Either modify the individual column like this:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE arabic CHANGE words words VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.16 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

This other post here might be of some help also [How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)

Example:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE arabic CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.88 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE arabic;
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table                                                  |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| arabic | CREATE TABLE `arabic` (
  `words` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: students
CREATE TABLE `students` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `first` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `uid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `dob` date NOT NULL,
 `dep` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `elevel` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `phone` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8