# #1273 – Unknown collation: ‘utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci’

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, collation

I have a WordPress website on my local **WAMP** server. But when I upload its database to live server, I get error

```
#1273 – Unknown collation: ‘utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci’
```

Comment: `sed -i 's/utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g' file.sql`

Comment: In a sea of find-and-replace solutions below, don't forget to checkout @SherylHohman's answer first - just upgrade to mariadb / mysql 5.6 so your server supports this collation.

Comment: What version of WordPress?  See https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/

Comment: There's also a quick guide here (https://wpza.net/unknown-collation-utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/) which explains all the 3-steps you should take to ensure you've done everything.

Comment: sed -i dump-file.sql -e 's/utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g'

Comment: [@thomasrutter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1820/thomasrutter) has an amazing explanation of *what* and *why* this is [here: "mysql to mariadb: unknown collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/314442/262276), and there are some great methods to alter collation the "right way" [here: "How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6115612/705296)

Comment: utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci (introduced in 2013) is very close to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci (2018).  This shows no diffs for typical accented letters: http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html

Answer (score 399, accepted):

You can solve this by finding

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

in your `.sql` file, and swapping it with

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: I recommend the answer by Sabba (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44122258/168309) as it retains the utf8mb4

Comment: The solution below of @Sabba Keynejad is better in my opinion, since it keeps the mb4, you should try that first.

Comment: Note, I had to replace this in multiple places in the SQL File. Also there were places where I had to do https://stackoverflow.com/a/44122258/1436129 below too.

Comment: Actually found this answered worked when the linked answer by Sabba did not. Presumably because of my MySql installation defaults. +1

Comment: it is not working, now it is giving error: `COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' `, i have replaced `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and it's working, as per Sabba's answer.

Comment: This is NOT a very correct answer, utf8 and utf8mb4 is not the same thing in mysql

Comment: I resolved it by replacing 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci' with 'utf8mb4_general_ci'

Comment: I changed `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` -->  `utf8mb4_general_ci`. mysql dist 5.7.33 on ubuntu 16 :) and it worked.

Comment: This answer worked for me.

Comment: for the utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci use utf8mb4_general_ci  Using for utf8_general_ci will create the following error.  #1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'  if using different CHARACTER SET

Answer (score 483):

I believe this error is caused because the local server and live server are running different versions of MySQL. To solve this:

1. Open the sql file in your text editor
2. Find and replace all `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
3. Save and upload to a fresh mySql db

[image]

Comment: **HELL NO!!!** It has been widely documented that `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` has *much* better UTF-8 support than `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`! Sauce: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#best_practice with visual clarification proving 520_ci is superior here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

Comment: @John, The articles you linked don't really defend that comment. Their "Thus" can't even be properly stated from their premise. Overall the whole article is poorly written, although there does appear to be some good information there. The 520 collation uses a newer version of the Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA - version 5.2.0) with different weights, but to say it "has much better UTF-8 support" seems more than a stretch.

Comment: Let's suppose that a Standards body (Unicode) will usually make each newer version (5.20) "better" than an older version (4.0).

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: I suggest this solution because it replaces all "utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci" occurrences. Whereas savani sandip answer leaves some.

Comment: faced similar issue for `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` , your solution worked perfectly

Comment: This was one of the best solution as I exported the data from mysql and importing in maria, i was facing issues and this helped finally. btw I've tried others too but was not working.

Comment: where can i find the sql file?

Answer (score 67):

In my case it turns out my
new server was running `MySQL 5.5`,
old server was running `MySQL 5.6`.
So I got this error when trying to import the `.sql` file I'd exported from my old server.

MySQL 5.5 does not support `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`,  but
MySQL 5.6 does.

**Updating to `MySQL 5.6` on the new server solved collation the error !**

If you want to retain MySQL 5.5, you can:
- make a copy of your exported `.sql` file
- replace instances of `utf8mb4unicode520_ci` and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`
...with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
- import your updated `.sql` file.

Comment: This is absolutely the best way to do it if you have full control over your server. Upgrade the new server so it matches the old server. If you don't have the access to upgrade your new server location, the find-replace method will probably be ok, but in any case where you can just do this upgrade instead, you should.

Comment: 5.6 is when _520_ was added.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Most of the other solutions are more like hacks. Thanks @SherylHohman

Answer (score 47):

Open the sql file in your text editor;

**1. Search:** utf8mb4_unicode_ci  **Replace:** utf8_general_ci **(Replace All)**

**2. Search:** utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci **Replace:** utf8_general_ci **(Replace All)**

**3. Search:** utf8mb4  **Replace:** utf8 **(Replace All)**

Save and upload!

Comment: I'm really glad I found your solution to this, I've been getting this #1273 error for days and I just couldn't find a solution to this

Answer (score 40):

I experienced a challenge importing data into mysql exported using mysql workbench. It is a collation issue.
I solved this error by:

1. Opening the .sql file using text editor
2. Replacing "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci" with "utf8mb4_general_ci".
3. Saving the file as .sql and importing it

It worked

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 36):

easy replace

```
sed -i 's/utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g' your_sql_file.sql
```

Comment: On macOS: ```sed -i '' 's/utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g' your_sql_file.sql```

Answer (score 22):

just remove "520_"
`utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` → `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Answer (score 18):

I just opened the dump.sql file in Notepad++ and hit CTRL+H to find and replace the string "**utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci**" and replaced it with "**utf8mb4_general_ci**".  Source link https://www.freakyjolly.com/resolved-when-i-faced-1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci-error/

Answer (score 12):

this error is caused because the conflict of different versions of MySQL. To solve this:

- Open the sql file in any text editor
- Find and replace all utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci with utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- Save and try new mySql db file

**after that try again,it works fine for me**
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Getting collation error #1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci' is caused by the difference of the MySQL version from which you export and our MySQL server to which you import. Basically, the Wordpress library for newer version checks to see what version of SQL your site is running on. If it uses MySQL version 5.6 or more, it assumes the use of a new and improved Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA) called “utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci”.  This is great unless you end up moving your WordPress site from a newer 5.6 version of MySQL to an older, pre 5.6 version of MySQL.

To resolve this you will either have to edit your SQL export file and do a search and replace, changing all instances of ‘utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci’ to ‘utf8mb4_unicode_ci’.  Or follow the steps below if you have a PHPMyAdmin:

1. Click the Export tab for the database
2. Click the Custom radio button.
3. Go the section titled Format-specific options and change the drop-down for Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with: from NONE to MYSQL40.
4. Scroll to the bottom and click GO.

Answer (score 8):

find and replace:

```
utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

with

```
utf8_general_ci
```

in whole sql file

Comment: `general` and `utf8` are both steps backward.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I substitute it with `utf8_general_ci` with sed like this:

```
sed -i 's/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8_general_ci/g' MY_DB.sql 
sed -i 's/utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/utf8_general_ci/g' MY_DB.sql
```

After that, I can import it without any issue.

Comment: If anyone is copying this command lines, the search is for utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, not utf8_0900_ai_ci

Answer (score 7):

I solved it this way, I opened the .sql file in a Notepad and clicked CTRL + H to find and replace the string "**utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci**" and replaced it with "**utf8mb4_general_ci**".

Answer (score 7):

I am facing the `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` this issue, I resolved it by using.

You just need to replace `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` with `utf8mb4_general_ci`

[image]

Comment: Your answer was already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69269659/8517948), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57151403/8517948), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67778445/8517948), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64050168/8517948), [here, but as shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58832266/8517948), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74341818/8517948) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75800025/8517948). As you have enough reputation you can upvote an existing answer instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 4):

**Use the sed command to replace text in files directly**

Linux OS

```
sed -i 's/utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/utf8mb4_general_ci/g' YOUR_SQL_FILE.sql
```

Mac OS

```
sed -i '' s/utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/utf8mb4_general_ci/g' YOUR_SQL_FILE.sql
```

*The help of this command i have fixed issue ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 51: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'*

Answer (score 4):

According to my experience, the destination's MySQL server is an older version than the source. The required database collation is not present on the destination server.

To fix this, we can make a small change to the backup file. Replace "utf8mb4 0900 ai ci" with "utf8mb4 general ci" and "CHARSET=utf8mb4" with "CHARSET=utf8" in the database backup file.

Replace the below string:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

with:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Save your file and restore the database.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but in case this happens with a `WORDPRESS` installation :

`#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`

In phpmyadmin, under `export method` > `Format-specific options`( custom export )

Set to : `MYSQL40`

If you will try to import now, you now might get another error message :

`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; .....`

That is because The older `TYPE` option that was synonymous with `ENGINE` was removed in MySQL 5.5.

Open your `.sql` file , search and replace all instances

from `TYPE=` to `ENGINE=`

Now the import should go smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

After a little investigation, I found that the MySQL server running on the destination is an older version than the source. So we got that the destination server doesn’t contain the required database collation.

Then we do a little tweak in the backup file to resolve this. Edit the database backup file(`your_sql_file.sql`) in a text editor and replace `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` with `utf8mb4_general_ci` and `CHARSET=utf8mb4` with `CHARSET=utf8`.

I hope this solution might help you.

Answer (score 0):

***1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'***

in my case I was unable to import DB using

```
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

and

```
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

both. But changing it to this in **.SQL File** resolved the problem

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

***UPDATED***

using '*utf8mb4_general_ci*'resolved the problem

```
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very strange that all answers recommend replacing collation. Which is a very bad practice because you want to use the same MySQL version as the one in development and the one in production. Therefore, your local mysql server should be the same.

First of all, Execute the query SHOW COLLATION to check all the collations your server supports. If you're using xampp or any other similar tool to start your server, it might come shipped with maria db server instead of mysql server.

What you should do is replace your current mysql (which is really mariadb) by the real mysql one.

So what you should do is simply replace your maria db server by mysql server.

Comment: Why not the other way around? ie change mysql to mariadb?

Comment: @crafter because by that time the collation was not supported for mariadb. Not sure if this changed.

Answer (score 0):

**In Addition**

For large .sql files, I recommend using HeidiSQL (a free and open-source database tool) and pressing Ctrl+O to load the file by browsing from the folder.

After that press Ctrl+f and replace the `"utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci"` (in my case) with `"utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci"` and save the file by pressing Ctrl+s.

Finally, rerun the DB upload process, and cheers.

Answer (score 0):

n your Laravel project, locate the config/database.php file. Inside this file, find the 'connections' array and look for the configuration related to your MySQL connection.

Within the MySQL connection configuration, add or update the 'collation' parameter to use a supported collation like 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

Answer (score -1):

I simply removed the `COLLATE` and other attributes and left only till `ENGINE`.
like the following

FROM:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=429 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

TO:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and it worked for me just fine.