# go to phpmyadmin first page get error #1273

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I installed wamp for first time and when i want to go to

> http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

for creating my first database, i see error

```
#1273 - unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'
```

I googling a lot and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385099/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-520-ci) solution which will solve #1273 error when importing databse. Is this solution also suitable for solving my problem (show phpmyadmin first page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved by uninstalling wamp2.1 and install wamp2.2.

Comment: Current version of WAMPServer is 3.1 maybe you would be better installing the latest version