# Wordpress Migration Issue 503 error

Tags: database, wordpress, migration

Recently I have revamped a website which is created on a development server. Then after that i started migrating it onto the main server. Initially I got a unicode error while uploading the database on the live server. I googled it and found a solution on stack overflow itself ([#1273 – Unknown collation: ‘utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385099/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-520-ci)). I used the method suggest by sabba and it worked. Later when I Changed the config file and loaded that link. Its giving me a 503 error.. It error is as follows:

**Service Unavailable**

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an Error Document to handle the request

Comment: check error_log in your main folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the steps and check it,

**Enable WP_DEBUG**

```
But since the 503 error often locks you out of your WordPress admin, we shall use WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG, WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY and @ini_set constants available to WordPress.

To enable debug mode in WordPress and write errors to a log file,  follow these steps:    

 1. Open the wp-config.php file
 2. Scroll down to where WP_DEBUG is defined. It looks like this define ('WP_DEBUG', false);. If it is missing, we will add it just above the line that says /*That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging.*/

 3. Insert the DEBUG magic codes. Just change the above define ('WP_DEBUG', false); code to:
    define ('WP_DEBUG', true);
    define ('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
    define ('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
    @ini_set ('display_errors', 0);

 4. Save changes

Now, reload your site to provoke the error. Next, locate a file known as debug.log inside your wp-content folder in your WordPress directory.

This file contains all the errors on your website. If your 503 service unavailable error is caused by a custom code snippet, it will show up somewhere with details of the error.

Eliminate/replace the problematic code and reload your site. If the 503 error persists, the problem could lie in your web server.
```