# Jenkins: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin returned status code 143:

Tags: git, jenkins

I haven't been able to build a job in Jenkins because I get the "status code 143:" error in the Build log. According to this [jenkins bug page](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36269), the error has to do with the repo taking longer than 10 minutes to fetch. So, as a solution, I changed some of the options for faster fetching, which are: uncheck "Fetch Tags", check "Shallow clone" and "Shallow clone depth" set to 1 and "Timeout (in minutes for clone and fetch operations" set to 20.

I'm attaching my configuration [here](https://i.postimg.cc/PxzXvRVF/screenshot.png)

[This](https://pastebin.com/MxGYusWD) is the build log from Jenkins:

This is my Jenkinsfile inside of the repo which I don't think jenkins hasn't been able to get to that point because of the timeout set to 10 minutes, which I can't change:

```
// Deployment template for CMS-based websites (Drupal or Wordpress)
// 
//
pipeline {
agent any

parameters {
    choice(choices: "Dev\nStaging\nProduction", description: "Choose which environment to push changes to.", name: "DEPLOY_TO")
    choice choices: "No\nYes", description: "Choose whether to deploy the database as well.", name: "DEPLOY_DB"
}

environment {
    SITEID = "ge"
    NOFLAGS = "0"
    DBNAME = "wpress_website"
    DBSERVER = "dbserver"
    DBUSER = "geWordpress"
    DBPASS = "akjh23kas"
    EXCLUDE = "comp_commentmeta,comp_comments"  // separate multiple tables with commas
    DEPLOY_TO = "${params.DEPLOY_TO}"
    DEPLOY_DB = "${params.DEPLOY_DB}"
}

stages {
    stage("deploy-db-dev") {
        when {
            allOf { 
                environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "dev"; 
                environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_DB", value: "yes"; 
            }
        }
        steps {
            // this stage only required until we make our dev the master DB
            // copy full dev database from appserv1
            // import latest database dump to dev server
            script {
                FILENM = sh(script: 'ls -t goewp-s-dump* | head -1', returnStdout: true)
            }
            //Fixing the problem with the collation existing in the sql dump file, refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385099/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-520-ci 
            //apparently, this is due to a version of mysql issue. Once the problem is fixed from the server side we can then remove the following lines. 

            sh "sed -i s/utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g ${FILENM}"
            //The following line was added because the site is pointing to a staging server which we don't have control over, again, once this is fixed we can delete the following line of code. 
            sh "sed -i s/edit.staging.websites.3pth.com/stage.goewpfoods.hcgweb.net/g ${FILENM}"

            sh "mysql -h appserver -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_dev < ${WORKSPACE}/${FILENM}"
        }
    }
    stage("deploy-dev") {
        when {
            environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "dev"
        }
        steps {
            // copy files to appserv2
            // NOTE: if we move the repo to SVN, we should change httpdocs/ to ${env.SITEID}docs/
            sh "sudo chown jenkins:jenkins *"

            //Replace the wp-config.php file with our comp file with our information. 
            sh "/bin/cp httpdocs/wp-config-comp.php httpdocs/wp-config.php"

            // prepare the dev server to receive files by changing the owner
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv2 \"sudo chown -R webadmin:webadmin /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            // copy files from control server to dev
            sh "rsync --exclude=Jenkinsfile -rav -e ssh --delete ${WORKSPACE}/httpdocs/ webadmin@appserv2:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/"
            // fix the owner/permissions on the dev server
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv2 \"sudo chown -R apache:${env.SITEID}-web /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv2 \"sudo chmod -R g+w /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv2 \"sudo find /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \\;\""
        }
    }
    stage("deploy-db-staging") {
        when {
            allOf { 
                environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "staging"; 
                environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_DB", value: "yes"; 
            }
        }
        steps {
            script {
                def myexcludes = env.EXCLUDE.split(',').toList()
                MYFLAGS = "-Q -K -c -e --default-character-set=utf8 "
                if (env.NOFLAGS == "0") {
                    myexcludes.each {
                        MYFLAGS = "${MYFLAGS} --ignore-table=${env.DBNAME}_dev.${it}"
                    }
                }
            }
            sh "cd ${WORKSPACE}"
            // pull a backup of the current dev database (may exclude some tables)
            sh "mysqldump -h appserv2 -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_dev ${MYFLAGS} > ${env.DBNAME}_dev.sql"
            // create a backup copy of the current staging database (full backup)
            sh "mysqldump -h ${env.DBSERVER} -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_stage > ${env.DBNAME}_stage_bak.sql"
            // upload the dev database dump to the staging database
            sh "mysql -h ${env.DBSERVER} -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_stage < ${WORKSPACE}/${env.DBNAME}_dev.sql"
        }
    }
    stage("deploy-staging") {
        when {
            environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "staging"
        }
        steps {
            // copy files from dev to control server
            sh "rsync --exclude=.svn --exclude=.git -rav -e ssh webadmin@appserv2:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/"

            //Replace the wp-config.php file with our comp file with our information. 
            sh "/bin/cp httpdocs/wp-config-comp.php httpdocs/wp-config.php"

            // prepare the staging server to receive files by changing the owner
            sh "ssh webadmin@stageserv \"sudo chown -R webadmin:webadmin /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            // copy files from control server to staging
            sh "rsync --exclude=.svn --exclude=.git -rav -e ssh --delete /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/ webadmin@stageserv:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/"
            // fix the owner/permissions on the staging server
            sh "ssh webadmin@stageserv \"sudo chown -R apache:${env.SITEID}-web /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            sh "ssh webadmin@stageserv \"sudo chmod -R g+w /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            sh "ssh webadmin@stageserv \"sudo find /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \\;\""

            // delete the temporary files on the control server
            sh "rm -Rf /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/"
            // clear the caches
            sh "wget -O - \"http://www.web.net/incacache.php?api_key=yoiVbjgtL&site_id=088\""
        }
    }
    stage("deploy-db-production") {
        when {
            allOf { 
                environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "production"; 
                environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_DB", value: "yes"; 
            }
        }
        steps {
            script {
                def myexcludes = env.EXCLUDE.split(',').toList()
                MYFLAGS = "-Q -K -c -e --default-character-set=utf8 "
                if (env.NOFLAGS == "0") {
                    myexcludes.each {
                        MYFLAGS = "${MYFLAGS} --ignore-table=${env.DBNAME}_stage.${it}"
                    }
                }
            }
            sh "cd ${WORKSPACE}"
            // pull a backup of the current staging database (may exclude some tables)
            sh "mysqldump -h ${env.DBSERVER} -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_stage ${MYFLAGS} > ${env.DBNAME}_stage.sql"
            // create a backup copy of the current production database (full backup)
            sh "mysqldump -h ${env.DBSERVER} -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_prod > ${env.DBNAME}_prod_bak.sql"
            // upload the staging database dump to the production database
            sh "mysql -h ${env.DBSERVER} -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_prod < ${WORKSPACE}/${env.DBNAME}_stage.sql"
        }
    }
    stage("deploy-production") {
        when {
            environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "production"
        }
        steps {
            // copy files from staging to control server
            sh "rsync --exclude=.svn --exclude=.git -rav -e ssh webadmin@stageserv:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/"

            // prepare the production server to receive files by changing the owner
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv3 \"sudo chown -R webadmin:webadmin /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv4 \"sudo chown -R webadmin:webadmin /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            // copy files from control server to production
            sh "rsync --exclude=.svn --exclude=.git -rav -e ssh --delete /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/ webadmin@appserv3:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/"
            sh "rsync --exclude=.svn --exclude=.git -rav -e ssh --delete /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/ webadmin@appserv4:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/"
            // fix the owner/permissions on the production server
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv3 \"sudo chown -R apache:${env.SITEID}-web /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv4 \"sudo chown -R apache:${env.SITEID}-web /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv3 \"sudo chmod -R g+w /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv4 \"sudo chmod -R g+w /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/\""
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv3 \"sudo find /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \\;\""
            sh "ssh webadmin@appserv4 \"sudo find /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \\;\""

            // delete the temporary files on the control server
            sh "rm -Rf /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/"
             // clear the caches
            sh "wget -O - \"http://www.web.net/incacache.php?api_key=yoiVbjgtL&site_id=088\""
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any help on this will be appreciated!

Comment: The real problem is : Why does it takes more than 10 minutes to fetch ?

Comment: @AndréDS is a big repo, around 3GB

Comment: Consider pasting your build log and Jenkinsfile right into this question. The links are dead.

Comment: @KenRachynski Thank you for pointing that out. I just updated the post with the right links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so everyone knows, my issue was related to a bug in the version of Jenkins I have (2.129). I just had to uncheck the option "Lightweight checkout" inside of the configuration for the Job. The problem seems to be with Bitbucket, it tries to make an API call to retrieve the Jenkinsfile first but it doesn't get any response from bitbucket and it times out. Hopefully that's helpful for anyone else having the same problem