# How to deploy in jenkins taking the source code from specific git branches depending on the parameter choice

Tags: git, jenkins

I would like to be able to build depending on the environment is chosen from the parameters for my project, for example, if the user select staging option in the parameter I would like the job to be build from the staging branch, if the user running the jenkins job selects production, I would like to build from the master branch. I'm using a pipeline deployment by the way.

My current Jenkinsfile looks currently like the following:

```
// Deployment template for CMS-based websites (Drupal or Wordpress)
//
//
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        choice choices: ['Dev', 'Staging', 'Production'], description: "Choose which environment to push changes to.", name: "DEPLOY_TO"
        booleanParam defaultValue: true, "Choose whether to deploy the database.", name: "DEPLOY_DB"
    }

    environment {
         SITEID = "lb"
        NOFLAGS = "0"
        DBNAME = "wpress_myproject"
        DBSERVER = "dbserver"
        DBUSER = "WordpressUser"
        DBPASS = "hiddenpassword"
        EXCLUDE = "domain_commentmeta,domain_comments"  // separate multiple tables with commas
        DEPLOY_TO = "${params.DEPLOY_TO}"
        DEPLOY_DB = "${params.DEPLOY_DB}"
    }

    stages {
        stage("deploy-db-dev") {
            when {
                allOf {
                    environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "dev";
                    environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_DB", value: "true";
                }
            }
            steps {
                // this stage only required until we make our dev the master DB
                // copy full dev database from bolwebdev1
                // import latest database dump to dev server
                script {
                    FILENM = sh(script: 'ls -t myproject-s-dump* | head -1', returnStdout: true)
                }
                //Fixing the problem with the collation existing in the sql dump file, refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385099/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-520-ci
                //apparently, this is due to a version of mysql issue. Once the problem is fixed from the server side we can then remove the following lines.

                sh """sed -i s/utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g ${FILENM}
                # The following line was added because the site is pointing to a staging server which we don't have control over, again, once this is fixed we can delete the following line of code.
                sed -i s/myproject.staging.websites.3pth.com/myproject.example.net/g ${FILENM}
                mysql -h devserver2 -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_dev < ${WORKSPACE}/${FILENM}
                rm -f ${WORKSPACE}/${FILENM}"""
        }
        }
        stage("deploy-dev") {
            when {
                environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "dev"
            }
            steps {
                // copy files to devserver2
                // NOTE: if we move the repo to SVN, we should change httpdocs/ to ${env.SITEID}docs/
                sh """sudo chown jenkins:jenkins *

                #Replace the wp-config.php file with our domain file with our information.
        /bin/cp httpdocs/wp-config-domain.php httpdocs/wp-config.php

                # prepare the dev server to receive files by changing the owner
                ssh webadmin@devserver2 'sudo chown -R webadmin:webadmin /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/'
                # copy files from control server to dev
                rsync --exclude=Jenkinsfile -rav -e ssh --delete ${WORKSPACE}/httpdocs/ webadmin@devserver2:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/
                # fix the owner/permissions on the dev server
        ssh webadmin@devserver2 'sudo chown -R apache:${env.SITEID}-web /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ && sudo chmod -R g+w /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ && sudo find /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \\;'"""
            }
        }
        stage("deploy-db-staging") {
            when {
                allOf {
                    environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "staging";
                    environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_DB", value: "true";
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    def myexcludes = env.EXCLUDE.split(',').toList()
                    MYFLAGS = "-Q -K -c -e --default-character-set=utf8 "
                    if (env.NOFLAGS == "0") {
                        myexcludes.each {
                            MYFLAGS = "${MYFLAGS} --ignore-table=${env.DBNAME}_dev.${it}"
                        }
                    }
                }
                // pull a backup of the current dev database (may exclude some tables)
                sh """mysqldump -h devserver2 -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_dev ${MYFLAGS} > ${env.DBNAME}_dev.sql
        #Searching and replace for the URL to change from the dev sever to the staging server
                sed -i s/myproject.example.net/stage-myproject.example.net/g ${env.DBNAME}_dev.sql

        # create a backup copy of the current staging database (full backup)
                mysqldump -h ${env.DBSERVER} -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_stage > ${env.DBNAME}_stage_bak.sql
                # upload the dev database dump to the staging database
                mysql -h ${env.DBSERVER} -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_stage < ${WORKSPACE}/${env.DBNAME}_dev.sql
                rm -f ${WORKSPACE}/${env.DBNAME}_dev.sql"""
       }
        }
        stage("deploy-staging") {
            when {
                environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "staging"
            }
            steps {
                // copy files from dev to control server
                sh """rsync --exclude=.svn --exclude=.git -rav -e ssh webadmin@devserver2:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/

                #Replace the wp-config.php file with our domain file with our information.
            /bin/cp httpdocs/wp-config-domain.php httpdocs/wp-config.php

                #prepare the staging server to receive files by changing the owner
                ssh webadmin@stageserver 'sudo chown -R webadmin:webadmin /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/'
                # copy files from control server to staging
                rsync --exclude=.svn --exclude=.git -rav -e ssh --delete /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/ webadmin@stageserver:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/
                # fix the owner/permissions on the staging server
                ssh webadmin@stageserver 'sudo chown -R apache:${env.SITEID}-web /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ && sudo chmod -R g+w /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ && sudo find /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \\;'

                #delete the temporary files on the control server
                rm -Rf /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/
                # clear the Incapsula caches
                if [[ \$( curl -sS -X POST \"http://www.example.net/incapcache.php?api_key=asdaswwGR)feasdsdda&site_id=stage&resource_url=stage-myproject.example.net\" | jq -r .debug_info.id_info) != \"incapsula cache cleared successfuly\" ]]; then exit 255; fi"""
            }
        }
        stage("deploy-db-production") {
            when {
                allOf {
                    environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "production";
                    environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_DB", value: "true";
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    def myexcludes = env.EXCLUDE.split(',').toList()
                    MYFLAGS = "-Q -K -c -e --default-character-set=utf8 "
                    if (env.NOFLAGS == "0") {
                        myexcludes.each {
                            MYFLAGS = "${MYFLAGS} --ignore-table=${env.DBNAME}_stage.${it}"
                        }
                    }
                }
                sh """cd ${WORKSPACE}
                # pull a backup of the current staging database (may exclude some tables)
                mysqldump -h ${env.DBSERVER} -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_stage ${MYFLAGS} > ${env.DBNAME}_stage.sql
        #Searching and replace for the URL to change from the stage sever to the prod server
                sed -i s/stage-myproject.example.net/www.myproject.com/g ${env.DBNAME}_stage.sql

                # create a backup copy of the current production database (full backup)
                mysqldump -h ${env.DBSERVER} -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_prod > ${env.DBNAME}_prod_bak.sql
                # upload the staging database dump to the production database
                mysql -h ${env.DBSERVER} -u ${env.DBUSER} --password='${env.DBPASS}' ${env.DBNAME}_prod < ${WORKSPACE}/${env.DBNAME}_stage.sql
                rm -f ${WORKSPACE}/${env.DBNAME}_stage.sql"""
        }
        }
        stage("deploy-production") {
            when {
                environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "production"
            }
            steps {
                // copy files from staging to control server
                sh """rsync --exclude=.svn --exclude=.git -rav -e ssh webadmin@stageserver:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/

                # prepare the production server to receive files by changing the owner
                ssh webadmin@prodserver1 'sudo chown -R webadmin:webadmin /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs'
                ssh webadmin@prodserver2 'sudo chown -R webadmin:webadmin /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs'
                # copy files from control server to production
                rsync --exclude=.svn --exclude=.git -rav -e ssh --delete /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/ webadmin@prodserver1:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/
                rsync --exclude=.svn --exclude=.git -rav -e ssh --delete /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/ webadmin@prodserver2:/var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/
                # fix the owner/permissions on the production server
                ssh webadmin@prodserver1 'sudo chown -R apache:${env.SITEID}-web /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/'
                ssh webadmin@prodserver2 'sudo chown -R apache:${env.SITEID}-web /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/'
                ssh webadmin@prodserver1 'sudo chmod -R g+w /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/'
                ssh webadmin@prodserver2 'sudo chmod -R g+w /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/'
                ssh webadmin@prodserver1 'sudo find /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \\;'
                ssh webadmin@prodserver2 'sudo find /var/opt/httpd/${env.SITEID}docs/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \\;'

                # delete the temporary files on the control server
                rm -Rf /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/
                # clear the Incapsula caches
                if [[ \$( curl -sS -X POST \"http://www.example.net/incapcache.php?api_key=asdaswwGR)feasdsdda&site_id=088&resource_url=www.myproject.com\" | jq -r .debug_info.id_info) != \"incapsula cache cleared successfuly\" ]]; then exit 255; fi"""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I see I can choose more than one branch in the options called "Branches to build"
 in my project's options UI, the question here becomes, how can I make Jenkins to select one branch or the other depending on the parameter option?

The next question would be, since I have polling enabled, and currently it works as follows: if there's a new push to the master branch jenkins starts to build the dev and staging stages and only when I want to deploy to production, I do it manually. Then, I would like to preserve this, but like I was asking above, I would like that polling would trigger a deployment from the staging branch and when I want to do it manually I would like to use the master branch, in other words, I would like polling to work only on one branch no all of the list of branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already added appropriate run conditions to the stages using the `when` directive, you can achieve the desired outcome with minimal changes as follows:

**Checkout a specific branch based on the selected environment**

1. In the job configuration page, under **Pipeline script from SCM**, select **Lightweight checkout**. This is to make Jenkins retrieve only the Jenkinsfile from the repository at the beginning of the build.
2. In the `Jenkinsfile`, add a function to checkout a repository on demand and then disable the default behavior of automatic checkout.

```
    // Checkout repository on demand
    def gitCheckout(branch) {
        checkout(
            [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "refs/heads/${branch}"]], 
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                extensions: [
                    [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],
                    [$class: 'CheckoutOption', timeout: 30],
                    [$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: true, timeout: 30],
                    [$class: 'AuthorInChangelog'],
                    [$class: 'PathRestriction']
                ],
                submoduleCfg: [],
                userRemoteConfigs: [
                    [credentialsId: 'myGitCrdentials', url: 'https://github.com']
                ]
            ]
        )
    }

    pipeline {
        agent any
        options {
            skipDefaultCheckout(true)  // Disable automatic checkout
        }
        parameters {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

3. Now, in the corresponding stages, call the `gitCheckout()` function with the required branch to build.

```
    stage("deploy-staging") {
        when {
            environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "staging"
        }
        steps {
            gitCheckout('staging')  // Checkout the staging branch
            // Do stuff here
        }
    }
```

**Poll only a single branch**

1. Since you want to poll only the staging branch, copy or move the `Jenkinsfile` to this branch.
2. In the job configuration page, under **Pipeline script from SCM** > **Branches to build**, enter `refs/heads/staging`.

This should meet both your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now, when you mention gitCheckout('staging'), where gitCheckout is defined?

Answer (score 0):

I use gitBranch for all my job in Job DSL Plugin

You can use snippet generator. Available for any pipeline job. Left side "Pipeline Syntax" >  "Snippet Generator" > git

```
def gitChekout(String gitBranch) {
   git( branch: gitBranch, 
        credentialsId: 'your-credentials', 
        url: 'git@ssh://path-ti/repo.git')
}
```

somewhere in pipeline

```
gitChekout('master')
```