# Cannot Migrate Laravel due to 'General error: 1273' and Where to Find SQL file?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I tried to learn laravel 11, by creating the table with command 'php artisan create:migration create_students_table', and then in the migration folder it comes with following codes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');  // I manually add this line
            $table->integer('score'); // and this line
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('students');
    }
};
```

then I checked the `.env` file with following content:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:IRJpq9MlMvgS9B/EhOMyEiI9Srz5C33cfMm6ngTritY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
APP_URL=http://localhost

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_FAKER_LOCALE=en_US

APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER=file
APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE=database

BCRYPT_ROUNDS=12

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_STACK=single
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=learning-laravel-11
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=null

BROADCAST_CONNECTION=log
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

CACHE_STORE=database
CACHE_PREFIX=

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=log
MAIL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

then I entered `php artisan migrate` and comes this error:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\learning-laravel-11> php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1273 Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'learning-laravel-11' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:813
    809▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    810▕                 );
    811▕             }
    812▕
  ➜ 813▕             throw new QueryException(
    814▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    815▕             );
    816▕         }
    817▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector.php:121
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1273 Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector.php:121
      PDO::exec("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', SESSION sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';")
```

I read the solution from [#1273 – Unknown collation: ‘utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385099/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-520-ci) but I didn't understand where are those SQL files directories.

Edit: Until today I still haven't found relevant answer on where those .sql directory located.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1273 – Unknown collation: ‘utf8mb4\_unicode\_520\_ci’](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76794815/446594)

Comment: @DarkBee is it inside my Laravel project directory or inside my MySQL directory?

Comment: You have to find out the source/location of the following query: "*PDO::exec("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', SE...*"  and replace the coalition accordingly