# Store the city name Łódź in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, collation, utf, character-set

I currently do have an address table in MYSQL, with its Character Set set to 'utf8' and Collation to 'utf8_unicode_ci'. There exists a column name *Address* and I am trying to store the city name Łódź into the *Address* column. I tried to key in directly into the table at SQLyog Community 64, as well as using the tool MYSQL for Excel but it keeps showing the error 'Incorrect string value'.

I have tried to set the Character Set set to 'utf8mb4' and Collation to 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'and it still gives me the same error.

Any help on how should I set the character set and collation in order to store Łódź? This city name is just one of many examples, and moving forward I may experience other similar characters as well. What can I use for a universal character set?

Comment: "I am trying to store the city name Łódź into the table" - *how* are you trying to do that? You haven't told us anything about what's trying to insert the data.

Comment: You should not just setup character set for MySQL, but also ensure that the program you are using for working with database also uses that character set.

Comment: Also execute `SHOW CREATE DATABASE your_db` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE table`  to see what charset is used in database and tables. Here is how to change charset for DB and tables if it's wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8

Comment: Hi @MichaelO., the query result is as shown CREATE DATABASE `for_cq_testing` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */

Comment: If you are using ODBC driver, check if it has UTF-8 option selected.

Comment: @MichaelO, thank you for your replies. But I am not sure why when i re-create the table, i am able to enter the values now.

Answer (score 0):

(`utf8` and `utf8mb4` work equally for Polish characters.)

You have not provided enough details about the flow of the characters, but the following should provide debugging for MySQL:

[Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

When stored correctly, the utf8 (or utf8mb4) encoding for `Łódź` is hex `C581 C3B3 64 C5BA`.