# Spring-Boot, Can't save unicode string in MySql using spring-data JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, unicode, spring-jdbc

I have my  `application.properties` set up like this :

```
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

And In my `pom.xml`I have property set up like this :

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <start-class>toyanathapi.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

My entity :
    @Entity
public class DailyRashifalEntity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String date;
private int rollno;
private String name;
//Constructors and getters/setters 
}
```

**Problem 1:**  If I use the above setup I get the exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA4\xA7\xE0\xA4\xBE...
```

**Problem 2 :** If I change the datasource url into this :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
```

The unicodes in my database get saved like this

```
 29 | 2074-03-04 |        3 | ?????????????? ?????,?????? ??????, ??????????? ????? ? ???? ???? ???? ??????
```

[image]

**How** can I **save** them in Mysql like they are in **unicode** **instead of** getting all the unicode data **converted** into `????????` .

Comment: drop the database and try again. u can set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create` for testing.

Comment: have you tried setting the charset on the connection as well ?

Comment: @premkumar no luck..

Comment: @FMashiro I am starting spring in last few days and I am not quite sure what is it like that you are telling . Can you explain plase ?

Comment: I think your database schema character encoding is not utf8. Could you check it executing the query:

SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE schema_name = "schemaName";

Comment: nevermind, you already do it. Ehm, what's the collation on your table ?

Comment: sorry again, what is collation of table, where is it defined ?  And I have updated my schema of @Entity can it be of some help for you to find whats wrong?

Comment: paste the output for `show create table DailyRashifalEntity ;`

Comment: create table my_table (id bigint not null auto_increment, date varchar(255), rashi_id integer not null, rashifal varchar(255), primary key (id))

Comment: paste output for `show create database dbname `

Comment: try this `CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

Comment: No luck again...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file change the following.

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
```

Answer (score 9):

Keep your hibernate configuration Like this

> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

And Change your DB Collation Like this

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

More information : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)

Comment: My project had the same issue you have described. and this worked for me.

Comment: Problem was not in my project, rather it was in mysql config in Mechine

Answer (score 3):

See "question marks" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .

Also,

```
⚈  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8 
⚈  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8 
⚈  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by applying to the column definition as shown below:

```
public class Goal{

@Column(name = "SOURCE_OF_FUNDS", length = 6000, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(6000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL")
private String sourceOfFunds;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want save non-ascii character correctly, you should make sure:

- **Created** MySQL table with charset=encoding is UTF-8
- **Connect** MySQL table with charset=encoding is UTF-8

following is how to achieve it:

## Create mysql table with utf-8 charset

### method 1 (I use this method): config in Spring Boot JPA

after refer another [Chinese post](https://blog.csdn.net/hhaojian/article/details/79243763), my final working configuration:

- file: `src/main/java/com/crifan/smartelectricserver/MySQL55DialectUtf8mb4.java`
- code:

```java
package com.crifan.smartelectricserver;

import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect;;
// import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect; // Deprecated

// public class MySQL5InnoDBDialectUtf8mb4 extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
public class MySQL55DialectUtf8mb4 extends MySQL55Dialect {
  @Override
  public String getTableTypeString() {
    return "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci";
  }
}
```

which set table charset to `utf8mb4` and collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

and

- file: `src/main/resources/application.properties`
- config:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=com.crifan.smartelectricserver.MySQL55DialectUtf8mb4
```

in which:

- `com.crifan.smartelectricserver.MySQL55DialectUtf8mb4`: corresponding above file `com/crifan/smartelectricserver/MySQL55DialectUtf8mb4.java`

### method 2: set utf-8 in MySQL config file `my.cnf`

find your `my.cnf` in your machine, edit to:

```
[client] 
default-character-set = utf8mb4 
[mysql] 
default-character-set = utf8mb4 
[mysqld] 
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE 
character-set-server = utf8mb4 
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

## Connect MySQL with UTF-8

- file: `src/main/resources/application.properties`
- config:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/smart_electric?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

in which:

- `useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`: means connect MySQL with charset utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Non of the answer worked for me … except the url encoding part.

The solution in my case is twofold:

1- Add encoding in the URL of Database config bean:

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customersdb?useSSL=false&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8" />
```

2- Add this configuration to your dispatcher config file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Otherwise, other configurations don't take effect.