# retrieve unicode data from database using spring java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

how to retrieve unicode data from mysql database using spring java

set the url like this

```
<property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
```

But when data is loaded what i get is ????

Comment: useUnicode=yes or useUnicode=true?

Comment: i used useUnicode=yes

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment cause my reputation, so I post here.

Have you checked your character set of table, database and column?

[How do I see what character set a MySQL database / table / column is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is)

my.cnf

[Spring-Boot, Can't save unicode string in MySql using spring-data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588055/spring-boot-cant-save-unicode-string-in-mysql-using-spring-data-jpa?rq=1)

Make sure your code IDE(or terminal) language to UTF8

[Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Sorry about many references, but encoding problem maybe have many cause.