# 1366, Incorrect string value django or collate or tables in mysql.

Tags: mysql, django, collate

When in django admin panel i try to add something in database using russian symbols - it gives me error:

```
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xD0\\xB2\\xD1\\x84\\xD1\\x8B' for column 'name' at row 1")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://giver.md/dev/admin/gift/categoryru/add/
Django Version: 1.10.4
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xD0\\xB2\\xD1\\x84\\xD1\\x8B' for column 'name' at row 1")
Exception Location: /home/ubuntu/giver/server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler, line 36
Python Executable:  /home/ubuntu/giver/server/bin/python2
Python Version: 2.7.12
```

I know, that i need to change collation to resolve this problem? But how can i collate al tables in my mysql database using ubuntu 16?
I tryed this, but this didn't helped me:

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_NAME," COLLATE utf8_general_ci") AS ExecuteTheString
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="giver"
```

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, you have to change collation. The easiest way is to drop your old database and create a new utf8 one. Just note that with dropping your database, all of your tables and data will be gone, so you have to create tables and superuser again. So:

1. Create a new utf8 database:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE <new_database_name> CHARACTER SET utf8;
   ```
2. If the name of new database differ from the old one, don't forget to change database name in your app setting.py file!
3. Create tables; Just simply migrate:

   ```
   $ python manage.py migrate
   ```
4. Create super user:

   ```
   $ python manage.py createsuperuser
   ```

If you have some important data in your database and you don't want to lose them, see [How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8#6115705)

or simply use proper tools to backup your data from old database and import them to the new utf8 created database.