# db connection charset and database setting, which is applied in advance to the others?

Tags: mysql

Programmers can set `charset` when  make connection to database in code.

If I set it to utf8mb4, does it applied to db ignoring current real DB setting?

Meaning, even if the real database `charset` setting is utf8?

If so, database encoding setting doesn't seem to be important.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read How do I ask  a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Both database connection setting and database setting should be utf8mb4 to save emojis correctly

Comment: you can read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8