# Joomla 3.8.2 wrong character encoding

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

My website is showing the wrong characters as you can see in the attached image, taken from google analytics:

[image]

Now, the problem is that these characters only show SOMETIMES, which I find very strange.

I've tried changing the database collation to utf-8 as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8).

And I've also tried using Admin tools "Change database collation" several times, and "Repair & Otimise tables" but nothing works.

Have also cleared cache and temp directory.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Frustratingly, there are lots of places the encoding can be wrong. Here is a [long discussion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html). Chances are the solution is the terribly-named `SET NAMES` directive.

Comment: this sucks.....