# Is there a way to perform accent-insensitive lookups using Django and MariaDB?

Tags: django, mariadb, django-queryset

I would like to make an accent-insensitive lookup in a french database (with words containing accents):

```
>>> User.objects.filter(first_name="Jeremy")

['<User: Jéremy>', '<User: Jérémy>', '<User: Jeremy>']
```

After lots of research, I found that Django has an [Unaccent](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#unaccent) lookup for PostgreSQL but nothing for other databases (like MariaDB)

Is there a way to make this happen **without changing** the database to PostgreSQL?

Comment: Could this be solved by changing the column's collation? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6da44/2

Comment: @MartinBurch I'm not very familiar with collation but found this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316327/how-to-set-collation-in-mysql-database-with-django-2-mysqlclient

if I got this right, by making this Alteration, I will have additional columns that contain the non-accentuated version of each cell?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that thread too, but I can't really recommend it. Basically, if you can alter your MySQL/MariaDB column's collation _once_, _in the database_ (might want to make a backup first) then _every_ query (not just the ones made in Django) will disregard the accents (and even upper/lower case, that's what _ci means). This won't change the database column contents at all, just how the comparison (`WHERE first_name = 'jeremy'`) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Finally got it solved:

So first and foremost: get acquainted with SQL Collations! (Thanks to @MartinBurch)
Collations set the searching rules so that SQL can match your given keywords.

So after lots of head-smashes, here is how I solved it:

1- head to your "my.cnf" file
(if you know where is your my.cnf, you can skip to step 5)

2- Open your terminal and type:

```
$ which mysqld
```

That should return "/usr/sbin/mysqld" or another path depending on your configuration.

3- Use the path returned in step 2 as follows:

```
$ /your/path/to/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
```

That should return something that finishes like:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf
```

4- Find the file that has a [mysqld] section. if none of them has one, just add it.
Note: writing the section's name is very important SQL won't start otherwise

5- Add the following lines at the end of the file and Save:

```
[mysqld]
character_set_server = latin1
collation-server =  latin1_general_ci
```

6- Restart your MariaDB server (if you have a brew version):

```
brew services stop mariadb
brew services start mariadb
```

7- head to your Django project and use '__icontains' to make case insensitive and accent insensitive queries:

```
User.objects.filter(name__icontains=jeremy)
>>> ['<User: Jéremy>', '<User: Jérémy>', '<User: Jeremy>']
```