# Django MySQL 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, which will be replaced by UTF8MB4

Tags: mysql, django, utf-8, utf8mb4

I am using Django 2.0.4, MySQL 8.0.11, mysqlclient-1.3.12 and Python 3.6.5 on Mac Sierra. I am receiving the following warning:

> /lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py:71: Warning: (3719, "'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, which will be replaced by UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.")

I know it's just a warning, but I still don't like seeing it and have been searching for a solution to it. I have tried a number of things including dropping and recreating my Schema with a variety of options from UTF8 Collation UTF8-bin and UTF8MB4 Collation UTF8MB4-bin but nothing seems to work. This warning is coming from MySQL/base.py but I don't know who is making the call with 'utf8' that MySQL is objecting to.

Anyone have any ideas?

ADDITIONAL INFO

I got to thinking about this some more after the answer below and realized that I have so far only received this warning during the migrate command during what appears to be the initial setup of the auth app.  I looked at all the sql with the sqlmigrate command and didn't see any mention of utf8 so I still don't know why it is happening

> (CL) Mac-mini:mysite Lehrian$ python manage.py migrate Operations to
>   perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, polls,
>   sessions Running migrations:   Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...
>   OK   Applying auth.0001_initial... OK   Applying admin.0001_initial...
>   OK   Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK   Applying
>   contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK   Applying
>   auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK   Applying
>   auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK   Applying
>   auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK   Applying
>   auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK   Applying
>   auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK   Applying
>   auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
>   /Users/Lehrian/Documents/Davelopment/CL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py:71:
>   Warning: (3719, "'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set
>   UTF8MB3, which will be replaced by UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please
>   consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.")   return
>   self.cursor.execute(query, args)   Applying
>   auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK   Applying
>   auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK   Applying
>   polls.0001_initial... OK   Applying polls.0002_auto_20180425_1458...
>   OK   Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK (CL) Mac-mini:mysite
>   Lehrian$

I also get it when running tests but I have concluded this is the same error as above as tests creates it's own database (also with character set utf8mb4, I preserved the test_polls database and looked at it) and it runs the same migration as above.

Comment: trademark capitalization; grammar; layout.

Answer (score 10):

`UTF-8` is what the world outside MySQL calls the Unicode encoding for any number of bytes.

`utf8` (no dash) is a `CHARACTER SET` in MySQL.  It is (currently) limited to 3-byte characters, hence does not include some Chinese and Emoji characters.

`utf8mb4` is the `CHARACTER SET` in MySQL that handles the 4-byte characters, too.

Although the Unicode standard allows for 5-byte characters, there will not be any in the near future.

Do not consider charsets `utf16` or `utf32` (UTF-16 or UTF-32).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-11.html says

> The utf8 character set is currently an alias for utf8mb3, but will at that point become a reference to utf8mb4. To avoid ambiguity about the meaning of utf8, consider specifying utf8mb4 explicitly for character set references instead of utf8.

Since you are using MySQL 8.0, which nicely handles the differences between utf8mb3 and utf8mb4 (versions 5.5 and 5.6 had some annoying incompatibilities), I see the warning as not a very big deal.

MySQL 8.0 defaults to `utf8mb4` and a newer collation than what 5.7 had.  So, databases initially created in 8.0 should be better off than in older versions.

I recommend (to all MySQL users) to use `utf8mb4`.  This should work "best" for the foreseeable future.  Doing so will avoid the confusion that may ensue when `utf8` changes from meaning `utf8mb3` to `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem, and even when my columns are set to `utf8mb4`, it was still failing to save things like certain emoji characters. Turns out, Django was not using the same character set when connecting to the database. To solve this, you can specify a new `OPTIONS` entry in the Django `DATABASES` setting, telling it which charset to use:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'xxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',  # <--- Use this
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the exact same issue lately.
I raised a bug request to Django, but Django do not accept it as their bug.

MySQL 8 has switched from UTF8MB3 to UTF8MB4 as the default charset. As of [8.0.11](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-11.html#mysqld-8-0-11-charset) if you access a table that was created with the previous version a warning is returned encouraging you to switch to UTF8MB4.

When you run the inspectdb the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables are still in UTF8MB3 so you get the warning returned to Django, which Django is currently unable to ignore.

I have a fully worked example of how to get around this error on the Django bug ticket:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29678

I have been able to fully use MySQL 8.0.12 as a backend for a robust Django application 
so once you get past this issue you should hopefully be okay.

I copied this text from another answer I added [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081773/django-inspectdb-utf8mb4-error/52211579#52211579), Apologies if that is bad etiquette

Answer (score 1):

It tell you that your database uses a type (UTF8), which it will changed in future.

So change the table settings, so that you specify the exact type.

[The reason in short: mysql now reserve 3 bytes encoded UTF-8 (UTF8MB3) per character, but you can force it to reserve 4 bytes (still encoded in UTF-8), using UTF8MB4. Considering that Unicode characters could require 4 bytes (in UTF-8 [and BTW also in UTF-16 and UTF-32]), the future default for 'utf-8' will be UTF8MB4. So the change and the warning.

Collation is used to compare equality and to order columns, but it is not the character set. People (and so answer) often confuse it, because it is displayed most prominently. (OTOH you should use a collation compatible with your character set).

This answer explain how to change character set and collation:

[How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)

Comment: My research pointed me to this conclusion however, I dropped the schema and recreated it with character set utf8mb4 and I still received the same warning.  I just double checked the schema details in MySQL and it is definitely utf8mb4.  So I am still at a loss as to why I am receiving this warning.  I can only assume that Django is doing something to cause it, but I don't know what.

Comment: The warnings seem originated by mysql. Check that your client mysql is updated, and also the python mysql module.

Comment: worked fine with mysql 8 and node js too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure If I am late, but in case anyone else gets stuck with this, here is something that worked for me.

---

Indexes in InnoDB tables can't be longer than 255 chars with utf8, but only 191 chars with utf8mb4. This means that the default indexes that Django makes for CharField(max_length=255) is too long.

You will need to update the VARCHAR length to less than 191 if it is set to 255 now.

Also set charset field to 'utf8mb4' specifically

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
  'USER': 'xxxxx',
  'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
  'HOST': 'localhost',
  'OPTIONS': {
      'charset': 'utf8mb4',  # The characterset you need
    }
  }
}
```