# django inspectdb utf8mb4 error

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf8mb4

Python manage.py inspectdb is giving following error even after all tables are 
 having CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci

from django.db import models

## Unable to inspect table 'execution'

## The error was: (3719, "3719: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.", None)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the exact same issue lately.
I raised a bug request to Django, but Django do not accept it as their bug.

MySQL 8 has switched from UTF8MB3 to UTF8MB4 as the default charset. As of [8.0.11](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-11.html#mysqld-8-0-11-charset) if you access a table that was created with the previous version a warning is returned encouraging you to switch to UTF8MB4.

When you run the inspectdb the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables are still in UTF8MB3 so you get the warning returned to Django, which Django is currently unable to ignore.

I have a fully worked example of how to get around this error on the Django bug ticket:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29678

I have been able to fully use MySQL 8.0.12 as a backend for a robust Django application 
so once you get past this issue you should hopefully be okay.