# Chinese character showing encoded format. How to fixed it

Tags: mysql

when we insert the Chinese character in mysql database but it will be show on encoded format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXCMB.png)

Comment: tform are Chinese character fields

Answer (score 0):

Setting encoding to UTF-8 while creating a table/database will help.

[Convert database to UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6115705/10796269)

Comment: Please tell me the process to convert this.