# When I store data from servlet to mysql database characters like "<", ">" are stored as unicode format like u003c rather than the actual symbol

Tags: mysql, database, servlets, unicode

I'm trying to store data in my database test like "< hi >" is stored as "u003c hi u004e" my database uses utf8mb4 charset. But also I experimented with utf8, utf 32, etc. It didn't work out.

Comment: change  mysql database encoding  to utf-8 or 16   follow the link https://www.a2hosting.in/kb/developer-corner/mysql/convert-mysql-database-utf-8

Comment: or try this link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6115705/7924858

Comment: I have found a solution. The problem is with gson library while creating json strings. not with the sql db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the Mysql Db. The problem is with gson/json library.

Use this code to solve it.

```
   Gson gsonBuilder =new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```