# MySQL: cannot save utf8 characters in database

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

[image]

Whenever I try to save an address with non-ascii characters like:

```
721-1 Higashishiokōjichō, Shimogyō-ku, Kyoto, 600-8216, Japan
```

Mysql fails with an error:

```
OperationalError(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC5\\x8Djich...' for column 'formatted_address' at row 1")
```

What is the best practice to save foreign language characters in database? 
Should I just ignore these characters in code? Or find a way to store them in MySQL (how?) ?

EDIT:

Ok after reading few articles, I tried changing the formatting of my database column from `latin1` to `utf8`. But the query just hangs and times out. Can anyone help?

```
ALTER TABLE <MYTABLE> MODIFY formatted_address TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

SOLVED:
this worked :) ->
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6115705/3520404

Comment: It's a different issue. In that post, the person is able to save non-ascii in database but having problems when retrieving it. However, I can't save them in DB in the first place,

Comment: @LinPy im using python. Found the solution thanks anyway.