# How do I create a Django migration to set charset and collation for all existing tables and all future ones?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, migration, collation

I'm using Django, Python 3.7 and MySql 5.7.  I want to set the default charset and collation for all existing and all future tables to

```
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I have already created some migrations,

```
(venv) localhost:maps davea$ ls web/maps/migrations/
0001_initial.py  __init__.py  __pycache__
```

Is there any way I can create such a migration?  I'm happy to blow away from database and start from scratch if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the CHARSET of the database, django has nothing to do with it:
[How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)

Comment: Perhaps I should ask a simpler question -- if I wanted to change the charset and collation of a single model (table) only, is that possible and how would that be done with a migration?

Comment: Incomplete -- Also change the default on each _table_ in case someone adds a column without specifying charset or collation.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem now where I tried creating a new record where the value of a `field_x` of type `django.db.models.TextField()` contains emoticons. It resulted to error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x99\\x82 :...' for column `db_name`.`table_name`.`field_x` at row 1")
```

I set the charset to utf8mb4 in the `proj/settings.py` specifically under the `DATABASES` field:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "any",
        "USER": "any",
        "PASSWORD": "any",
        "HOST": "any",
        "PORT": "any",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "charset": "utf8mb4",
        },
    }
}
```

The creation of the record became successful. Also, fetching the created record shows that it correctly contains the saved emoticons.

```
>>> record = TableName.objects.get(id=93)
>>> record.field_x
'masters trickeds us!!!      MYYYYY PRECIOOOOOUS~!  :)  :) ^_^^__^'
```

Some further reference you could check:

- http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/03/31/using-emojis-in-django-model-fields