# How to echo database content safely without foreign characters

Tags: php, html, css, database, echo

I built a PHP web page and some of the characters are like this

```
â‡¾ .... 
â€....
etc
```

Please help me on how to eliminate this

Comment: What database?  What platform?  Looks like a character set issue; what locale is set for the server where your PHP web page defined?  Also, please [edit] your question and  remove the `css` tag and add the `php` tag.

Comment: am using codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using UTF-8 characterset, I would try to change the encoding of the database to avoid these characters:
[How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)