# How to properly insert non english characters using PDO php and mysql

Tags: php

Am trying to insert korean characters to mysql leveraging PHP  Pdo and mysql. When I insert charcater  **다시 말해 주세요**  it shows **?? ?? ???** inside mysql database

**Here is how I created table**

```
create table base_tab (id int primary key auto_increment, content text, username varchar(20)) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**here is the code**

```
$db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb_test;charset=utf8', 
    'root', // username
    ''// password

);

$timer =  time();
$statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO base_tab
(content,username)
 
                          values
(:content,:username)');

$statement->execute(array( 

':content' => '다시 말해 주세요',
':username' => 'ann'
));


if($statement){

echo "success";
}else{

echo "failed";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to enable CJK, and select one of the various options when creating your Database, Table or Columns.

[Documentation](https://documentation.help/MySQL-5.0/ch10s10.html)

For `Korean` use

1. `euckr character set`

For `Japanese` use

1. `sjis character set`
2. `ujis character set`
3. `cp932 character set`

For `Chinese` use

1. `big5 character set`

#### Show what the current settings are:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repeat your problem, so I went through the following steps but didn't face any issues:

**1.** Created a new database with the **mydb_test** name and **utf8_general_ci** character set:
[image]

**2.** Copied your code and executed, returned "Success" and inserted data just correctly
[image]

So, I think the point is the database charset that needs to be **utf8_general_ci** upon creation :)

**Edit:** Change **utf8_unicode_ci** to **utf8_general_ci** when creating the table, it should be like this:

```
create table base_tab (id int primary key auto_increment, content text, username varchar(20)) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Can you create a sample with my code @Mohandes

Comment: You mean 'Can I insert data with your code?', yes I can, your code just works fine, the problem is with the database charset.

Comment: I also edited the answer(changed utf8mb4 to utf8), please check :)

Comment: Please show me how you create your database with utf8mb4 or utf8 because  my own is throwing error

Comment: I created that using phpmyadmin, you can also use phpmyadmin if you have access to it.

Comment: @Mohandes , You may find this helpful. [How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)