# SQL Corrupt - someone help me to recover

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wanted to know if it is possible to recover a .SQL file that was corrupted, the HD was formatted and I forgot to backup it. I used a program to recover and the file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: what kind of content are you expecting the .sql file to have? just ascii text, or did it contain a dump about binary files, or text using some non-common language? That has an impact on how you should approach this. If it's supposed to contain ascii text, this does not look like that at all, so it is possible the software you used just didn't work out in recovering.

Comment: A .sql file should contain SQL commands (and maybe some comments), so it should have readable text.

Comment: Maybe you see zip file content of sql file? Try unzipping it.

Comment: eis. -  It's a table backup I did.
Luuk. - How do I resolve it?
Justinas. - It's not a zip file.

Comment: Did you try to open it in another text editor? If you still getting the same in another text editor, it is surely an encoding problem. You have a different encoding in your database. Please try to set character set encoding in your database to UTF-8

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8