# How to convert a MySQL table's character set and collation to UTF-8?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

This has been asked before and answered: [How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)

The right answer is along the lines of:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

However, there is a comment on that answer, which describes the problem I am facing:

> The CONVERT TO technique assumes that the text
> was correctly stored in some other charset (eg, latin1), and not
> mangled (such as UTF-8 bytes crammed into latin1 column without
> conversion to latin1). – Rick James Apr 19, 2017 at 16:03

I have a table that uses cp1252 encoding and latin1_bin collation. It stores "PelÃ©" instead of "Pelé". After running the above command, such mangled text has no change so it remains mangled. If it matters, the reading application is on PHP.

How can I fix my data in the database?

Comment: How are you setting the connection charset when connecting to MySQL from your PHP application? There are many layers in play here; if you need to fix existing data, you might have to export, convert and then import it again.

Comment: That's Mojibake.  Study https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  And the link to possible fixes.