# MySQL: two different values in MySQL tables are treated as the same (can't set unique key)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, collation, cyrillic

I have dumped my small MySQL table (manually reduced to localize the problem) to show it here:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;



CREATE TABLE `symb` (
  `smb` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `trtmnt` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `symb` (`smb`, `trtmnt`) VALUES
('і', 'ty'),
('ї', 'hr');


/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

If you create the MySQL  table above and run this query

```
select * from symb where smb = 'ї';
```

or this one (**queries are different - please see the symbols 'ї' vs 'і'**)

```
select * from symb where smb = 'і';
```

then you may see you get two rows selected instead of one as I would expect.

To reemphasize, these two select queries above are different - the symbol 'ї' is different from 'і'  (both are cyrillic symbols, 'і' is NOT latin here).

```
Collation chosen was utf8_general_ci
```

Any reasons why 'і' and 'ї' are treated as the same symbols and what's the proper way to make it different? I need to select the exact row, not two.

Queries above were tested in phpMyAdmin and HeidiSQL which means that's MySQL (collation?) issue, not the program used to run queries.
Each different symbol should be treated as a different symbol and the table should be case sensitive. What's wrong with the table above? As result I'm unable to set unique key for this row.

Thank you.

Just added based on comments:
What does SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'symb' show you? 
It shows me:

```
Name    symb
Engine  InnoDB
Version 10
Row_format  Compact
Rows    2
Avg_row_length  8192
Data_length 16384
Max_data_length 0
Index_length    0
Data_free   0
Auto_increment  NULL
Create_time 22.05.16 12:11
Update_time NULL
Check_time  NULL
Collation   utf8_general_ci
Checksum    NULL
Create_options  
Comment
```

Comment: What does `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'symb'` show you?

Comment: make utf8_general_ci in each column

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , I've posted the answer on your question with my results of my table at the end of my question. Thank you.

Comment: One more question: Was this table UTF-8 encoded _before_ you inserted the two records in question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Not sure about the answer on your this question... Do you mean this piece of code CHARSET=utf8  in the CREATE TABLE `symb` as it is mentioned above? Then I guess the answer is Yes - please see utf8 in the create table above. Is this correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `SELECT` statement is returning both records, it appears that your data has already been encoded wrongly into UTF-8.  So merely changing the encoding of the `smb` column from Latin1 to UTF-8 won't work.  One option for you would be to dump the database to binary, and then reimport it as UTF-8:

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table your_database | replace CHARSET=latin1 CHARSET=utf8 |
    iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 | mysql your_database
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903318/how-do-i-change-a-mysql-table-to-utf-8) and [here](https://blogs.harvard.edu/djcp/2010/01/convert-mysql-database-from-latin1-to-utf8-the-right-way/) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

That is the way, how the collation chosen by you works. You can look here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1036459/4099089

Comment: Thank you for the link. Am I right the recommended table should be utf8_unicode_ci? Am I right I should create a COMPLETELY new table without converting the existing table?  Are both questions have the recommended answer YES? Thank you.

Comment: Michał , I've followed your recommendations - started from scratch with utf8_unicode_ci. The problem with 'ї' vs 'і' resolved. Another similar problem appeared - the same issue with ґ vs г. Any ideas how to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know. I would look at other collations and try to check online if there are no recommendations about best collation for your language.

Answer (score 1):

Which do you want?

```
D197       1111=x0457  [ї]    L  CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER YI
C3AF        239=x00EF  [ï]    L  LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS
```

If you do `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` you should get either `D197` or `C3AF` for a correctly stored `YI` or `i-umlaut`.  That is the best way to tell if it was stored correctly as utf8 (or utf8mb4).

They look the same, but they are treated differently.  All the utf8/utf8mb4 collations sort all Cyrillic letters after all Latin letters.

The "best" "general" collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.  (utf8, instead of utf8mb4, is ok if you don't need Chinese or Emoji.)

[Here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) is my rundown of how Western European characters compare in various utf8/utf8mb4 collations.  utf8_spanish2_ci, for example, is the only one to treat `ll` as a 'separate character', after all other `l` values.  utf8_latvian_ci handles `Ķ` and `Ļ` as separate letters.  Etc.

`SHOW TABLE STATUS` shows the *default* for the table; you need to look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see if any column overrides that default.

Comment: Thank you for your post very much. I chose utf8_bin and looks like that was an acceptable solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved* this issue in the following way:

1) Change table collation to utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

This allows you to insert all letters in Ukrainian alphabet except for ґ.
This also allows you to sort letters the way they are supposed to.

2) Change column collation to utf8mb4_bin

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

This allows you to insert ґ character.

*The only drawback of this approach is that when sorting you have to use

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci ASC
```

But still, it won't sort DESC